# Is it possible to avoid threads in multiplayer Hangman game?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I wish to implement a simple multiplayer Hangman game with the rule slightly bended.

Rule:
All the players have to guess the alphabets in the word at the same time. Whoever player guesses a correct alphabet gets a point, and the player who puts the ending alphabet gets bonus points.
This will be about speed. The faster correct guess gets you ahead of others.

I intend to have a Qt/QML based GUI and the programming language will be C++. Platform will be Linux.

I am thinking I'll need:
- One thread for handling user typing.
- Second thread for parallel display of what other players are typing.
- Third thread for parallel display of scores of every player on every player's screen.

Do I need these 3 threads or I am barking the wrong tree?

Comment: You don't _need_ threads for this.  Could be accomplished using something like `boost::asio` rather easily in one thread.  However, almost all UI frameworks like to have a dedicated thread to stay responsive to user input (in the presence of length background tasks).  So, for this case, I'd suggest two threads, one for `Qt` and the other for the "game logic" implemented in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: @Chad thanks for responding. `So, for this case, I'd suggest two threads, one for Qt and the other for the "game logic" implemented in an asynchronous manner.` Please explain the above quote in a somewhat detailed way in an "answer". Secondly, in case I won't be using boost library, then will it be necessary to use threads?

Comment: No you don't need threads for such lightweight tasks. You also don't need Boost for a typical Qt application. Qt is a complete (some would say bloated) framework, and Qt::Application has an event loop, so make use of it.

Comment: Yep, just write a perfectly normal, simple Qt application, where you handle events and don't block event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're planning to have this game communicating over the network, where each player is using their own computers and running a copy of the program.

You should only need one thread for the application, but you might decided that more threads will make it easier on you.

You can easily connect signals from player's typing (either use an event handler, or connect your widget's "editingDone" signal.) to the appropriate logic for updating the scores and showing the other player's answers.

I think you'll run into the most problems with deciding on how to properly network the application to all instances, assuming that that's what you're trying to do. But the Qt network stack can allow you to do asynchronous network communication without having to manually create new threads.